# Swift 3 Geofencing issues

Tags: ios, swift3, geofencing

below some of my code where I have 4 to 5 addresses and I want to monitor it using geofencing. When it starts monitoring the regions, I can see on my console the name of the locations which are correct.

The problem is when simulate to get to one location, it gives me the alert to the wrong location, it is always gives me the Chaus Restaurant and it should be the Schreiner Home one.

I put the break point on the Did enter regions and the code stops there for all regions... Why it just triggers when I enter on the correct location? Right now it takes as I am entering in all of the regions.

this json is what I get back

```
[
{
locationid: 1,
latitude: 37.8037522,
longitude: -121.9871216,
islocationactive: 1,
locationtitle: "Schreiner's Home",
locationsubtitle: "Danville"
},
{
locationid: 2,
latitude: 37.8191921,
longitude: -122.0071005,
islocationactive: 1,
locationtitle: "Montair",
locationsubtitle: "Elementary School"
},
{
locationid: 3,
latitude: 37.8186077,
longitude: -121.999046,
islocationactive: 1,
locationtitle: "Chaus Restaurant",
locationsubtitle: "Americas Eats"
},
{
locationid: 4,
latitude: 37.7789669,
longitude: -121.9829908,
islocationactive: 1,
locationtitle: "Valley",
locationsubtitle: "Cheer & Dance"
}
]
```

Thanks
Rodrigo

```
func GetAllILocations(){
        if let url = URL(string: "http://www.goemobile.com/mobile/liquidnitro/getlocations.php"){
            var request = URLRequest(url:url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST";// Compose a query string
            let postString = ""
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request) { data, response, error in

                if error != nil{

                    return
                }
                do {
                    if let convertedJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] {

                        for location in convertedJson {
                            if  ((location["locationid"] as? Int)! > 0) {
                                let latitude = location["latitude"] as! Double
                                let longitude = location["longitude"] as! Double
                                let title = location["locationtitle"] as! String
                                let subtitle = location["locationsubtitle"] as? String

                                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

                                annotation.title = title
                                annotation.subtitle = subtitle
                                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                                let region = CLCircularRegion(center: (self.locationManger.location?.coordinate)!, radius: 0.5, identifier: title)
                                self.locationManger .startMonitoring(for: region)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringFor region: CLRegion) {
        print("Hi \(region.identifier)")

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        if region is CLCircularRegion {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: region.identifier, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: radius is in meters.  0.5m is way too small.  Radius should me more like 100

Answer (score 0):

I found out.

The problem was on this line

```
let region = CLCircularRegion(center: (self.locationManger.location?.coordinate)!, radius: 0.5, identifier: title)
```

I was always using the user locations information instead the ones that came from the json.

I've changed with this

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
let region = CLCircularRegion.init(center: center, radius: 0.025, identifier: title)
```